# An 'if' statement with numbers

Tags: vb.net

I just bought a pool, and I am developing a log program to measure the chemicals every day. Rather than looking up what the chemical is supposed to be, I will build it into my program, the below statement isn't working properly. Even if I put in a 6, `Level Perfect` still shows up in my label:

```
If FCI__Free_Cholorine_ppmTextBox.Text < "1" Then
            lbfci.Text = "Level Too low"
        ElseIf FCI__Free_Cholorine_ppmTextBox.Text > "0" Then
            lbfci.Text = "Level Perfect"
        ElseIf FCI__Free_Cholorine_ppmTextBox.Text <= "4" Then
            lbfci.Text = "Level Perfect"
        ElseIf FCI__Free_Cholorine_ppmTextBox.Text > "4" Then
            lbfci.Text = "Level Too High"
        End If
```

Comment: set `Option Strict On` and the IDE will tell you that you are trying to treat strings as numerics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the strings to numbers then use an if / elseif.  The order of checks is important

```
Private Sub FCI__Free_Cholorine_ppmTextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles FCI__Free_Cholorine_ppmTextBox.TextChanged
    Dim lvl As Decimal
    If Decimal.TryParse(FCI__Free_Cholorine_ppmTextBox.Text, lvl) Then
        'the order of checking is important
        If lvl > 4 Then '5,6,7,etc.
            lbfci.Text = "Level Too High"
        ElseIf lvl > 0 Then '1,2,3,4
            lbfci.Text = "Level Perfect"
        Else
            lbfci.Text = "Level Too low"
        End If
    Else
        lbfci.Text = "Numbers only"
    End If
End Sub
```

This demonstrates why string comparisons are not a good idea in this case

```
    Dim s As String = "10"
    Dim s1 As String = "4"
    If s > s1 Then
        Stop
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should parse the contents of the textbox as an Integer first using the `Integer.TryParse` method in order to cut out any mistakes the user may have made entering the number into the textbox.

```
' First initialize a String variable and Trim any whitespace
Dim s As String = FCI__Free_Cholorine_ppmTextBox.Text.ToString().Trim()
Dim num As Integer
    ' Integer.TryParse returns True if it has successfully parsed the String into an Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(s, num) Then
        If num > 4 Then
          lbfci.Text = "Level Too High"
        ElseIf num > 0 Then
          lbfci.Text = "Level Perfect"
        Else
          lbfci.Text = "Level Too low"
        End If
    Else
            lbfci.Text = "Not a number"
    End If
```

Comment: This won't work because of the order of checks.  See the answer I submitted.

Comment: That's better.  Shorter also.